# After inserting list into a set, set only contains the items in list but not list

Tags: python, list, set

I'm trying to filter out unique items from a list of lists and have tried the following:

Data: `sent_list = [['cleverness', 'wit'],['the', 'best', 'story'],['best', 'story'],['wit']]`

I have tried:

```
word_set = set()
for sent in sent_list:
    for word in sent:
        word_set.update(word)

word_set
```

Output was:

```
{'b', 'c', 'e', 'h', 'i', 'l', 'n', 'o', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'y'}
```

But the expected code and result was:

```
word_set = set()
for sent in sent_list:
    word_set.update(sent)
word_set

{'best', 'cleverness', 'story', 'the', 'wit'}
```

I used the first 'for' loop for loop to access each sublist in the main list, then a second 'for' loop to access each word in the sublist, but seems my understanding is wrong. Also, in the correct code, if a list is directly updated to set, set should have lists in it, isn't it?
Please help me in understanding this concept.

Comment: Did you mean: `word_set.add(word)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use 'add' method to add only one element to list. 'update' method adds multiple elements. That is why it considers a string as an array of characters. Correct code would be

```
word_set = set()
for sent in sent_list:
    word_set.update(sent)
word_set
```

Comment: He could still use his original code but instead of using `update` method, he needs to use the `add` method and it will work in the same way.

Comment: That's true, but I think that my variant is a bit cleaner

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

The right method to use here is set.add(word) not set.update(word).